# Oracle sql retrive records based on maximum time

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i have below data.

```
table A

id   

1

2

3

table B

id       name      data1        data2     datetime

1        cash      12345.00                12/12/2012 11:10:12

1        quantity   222.12                  14/12/2012 11:10:12

1        date     20/12/2012               12/12/2012 11:10:12

1        date     19/12/2012                13/12/2012 11:10:12

1        date     13/12/2012                14/12/2012 11:10:12

1        quantity   330.10                   17/12/2012 11:10:12
```

I want to retrieve data in one row like below:

```
tableA.id      tableB.cash        tableB.date     tableB.quantity 

1               12345.00          13/12/2012       330.10
```

I want to retrieve based on max(datetime).

Comment: people are going to want to know what data type your order_time is

Comment: It would also help to explain exactly what results you would expect given this data and why.  It seems very, very odd that you have two rows with the same `order_id` in the `order` table.  But then both of them have the same `order_time` and `order_name` as well so we can't even pick the row with the most recent `order_time` for a particular `order_id`.  It is odd that you would have an `order_id` column in the `customer` table rather than creating an intersection table.  And then you have one order going to two different customers which seems even more wrong.

Comment: order_time format is YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS

Comment: @Justin:Updated order_time.that is the design having.same customer can order same item multiple times .

Comment: So `order_time` is a `VARCHAR2`?  Rather than a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP`?  What results would you expect given this data?  How do you know whether to pull the `customer_name` for `customer_id` 1 or 2 if both map to the same `order_id` and `order_id` is not unique?

Comment: yes it is varchar2. i got you ,updated my question.please check.sorry for this

Comment: @user1726550 - OK.  What would the expected results be?  How do you know whether to pull the `customer_name` for `customer_id` 1 or 2 if both map to the same `order_id` and `order_id` is not unique?  Any chance of fixing the data model so that `order_time` is an actual `DATE` and so that you have an intersection table between `customer` and `order`?  And that's before addressing the fact that it makes no sense to allow `order_id` to be duplicated.  Plus, this question is tagged both `MySQL` and `Oracle`-- which database are you really using?

Comment: order id in order table is not unique ,date and time data is varchar2,there is no intersection table between order and customer,order_id is duplicated,that is the way data populates.I need it for oracle.

Comment: @user1726550 - What would the expected results be? How do you know whether to pull the `customer_name` for `customer_id` 1 or 2 if both map to the same `order_id` and `order_id` is not unique?

Comment: Do ***not*** store dates (or numbers) in a `VARCHAR` column. Just don't

Comment: @user1726550 - I was really hoping that eventually you would answer the question I asked a few times-- what would the expected results be?  I posted my guess not knowing your actual requirements.

Comment: Wow...  That is a completely different question than the one you posted initially.  Are 'date1`, `date2`, and `date3` the only rows that you want to combine where the `name` is different?  Or might there be `cash1` and `quantity2` rows as well?  What role does the `data2` column play?  Or can we ignore that?  Is the `tableB.date1` column name hard coded?  Or might you want to get three columns of output for `date1`, `date2`, and `date3`?  Do you want the number of output columns to be dynamic based on the data in the table?

Comment: chnaged sample data,date1,date2,date2 are same i.e date.data2 we can ignore that.I know the name of outpu columns.can you please provide sql based on output i given

Answer (score 2):

The data model appears to be insane-- it makes no sense to join an `ORDER_ID` to a `CUSTOMER_ID`.  It makes no sense to store dates in a `VARCHAR2` column.  It makes no sense to have no relationship between a `CUSTOMER` and an `ORDER`.  It makes no sense to have two rows in the `ORDER` table with the same `ORDER_ID`.  `ORDER` is also a reserved word so you cannot use that as a table name.  My best guess is that you want something like

```
select * 
  from customer c 
       join (select order_id, 
                    rank() over (partition by order_id 
                                     order by to_date( order_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS' ) desc ) rnk
               from order) o on (c.customer_id=o.order_id)
 where o.rnk = 1
```

If that is not what you want, please (as I asked a few times in the comments) post the expected output.

These are the results I get with my query and your sample data (fixing the name of the `ORDER` table so that it is actually valid)

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with orders as (
  2    select 1 order_id, 'iphone' order_name, '20121201 12:20:23' order_time from dual union all
  3    select 1, 'iphone', '20121201 12:22:23' from dual union all
  4    select 2, 'nokia', '20110101 13:20:20' from dual ),
  5   customer as (
  6    select 1 customer_id, 'paul' customer_name from dual union all
  7    select 2, 'stuart' from dual union all
  8    select 3, 'mike' from dual
  9  )
 10  select *
 11    from customer c
 12         join (select order_id,
 13                      rank() over (partition by order_id
 14                                       order by to_date( order_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS' ) desc ) rnk
 15                 from orders) o on (c.customer_id=o.order_id)
 16*  where o.rnk = 1
SQL> /

CUSTOMER_ID CUSTOM   ORDER_ID        RNK
----------- ------ ---------- ----------
          1 paul            1          1
          2 stuart          2          1
```

Comment: unfortunately your solution giving lot of duplicates,every record displaying 3 times.

Comment: @user1726550 - This is why I asked repeatedly for you to post your expected output.  I edited my question to include the actual output of my query with your sample data.  If that is not the output you want, please tell us exactly what output you want.  If the query works for the sample data that you posted but the sample data does not include some data conditions which create issues, post more sample data.

Comment: i dont know,i given exact data.one table 'A' have unique values say id='1',other table 'b' has same id =1 in n number of times.I have to get data from both tables based on maximum date and time from table b.

Comment: @user1726550 - That's what the query I provided does-- see the example I posted using your sample data.  If that's not what you are seeing, that implies that you are either using a different query or that your data is different than the sample data you posted or that you want results that are different than what I'm guessing.  You need to tell us exactly what output you want for a particular set of sample data.  If we're guessing incorrectly, you have to tell us what is correct.

Comment: @user1726550 - First, I don't see any updates.  Second, if you do include more sample data, please also tell us *exactly* what output you would want for that sample data.  I showed you exactly what the query I posted would return for the sample data you have posted thus far.  You haven't told us whether that output is correct and, if not, what output you would want instead.

Comment: i provide everything,please check

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMER c
  INNER JOIN ORDER o
    ON (o.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID)
  WHERE TO_DATE(o.ORDER_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') =
    (SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(o.ORDER_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')) FROM ORDER)
```

Share and enjoy.